# Changed the Windows user password that Plesk used and I now I have a 500 error in my Plesk control panel

Tags: plesk

My boss forgot the password of the VPS where we host Plesk, so I changed it manually and now when I try to enter to the control panel outside the VPS I get a 500 error.

Does somebody knows where is the config of Plesk to change the windows' password?

Comment: What is the name of Windows user for which you have changed the password? What is the Plesk version and Windows version?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Plesk Panel doesn't allow any manual changes on web.config file for security reasons. You should change it from ASP.Net settings under Websites&Domains tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your Windows VPS server - if you need an access to the PLESK and you dont know the password - the solution is very simple - you need to access mysql database and reset the password from there:

Connect to your Windows dedicated server using Remote Desktop Connection.
From the Start menu, select Run.
In the Run dialog, type:
"%plesk_bin%\plesksrvclient" -get

http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/473
or
https://support.managed.com/kb/a553/retrieving-and-changing-plesk-admin-password.aspx